# How to set up a counter in Phaser's update method properly?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I am new to Phaser. The code snippet is as follows and collisionCnt here is globally initialised as 0:

```
  update: function() {

      this.collisionChecker = this.physics.arcade.collide(this.ground, this.rainGroup, this.over, this.overCheck, this);     //checks for collision between rain drops and ground
      this.physics.arcade.collide(this.rainGroup, this.rainGroup);      //checks for collision between rain drops


  },

  overCheck: function() {
      collisionCnt++;
      if(collisionCnt == 4) {
        console.log(collisionCnt);
        return true;
      }
      else {
        console.log(collisionCnt);
        return false;
      }
  },

  over: function() {
    this.state.start('gameOver');
  }
```

The problem is update method continuously monitors an instance of collision and returns true continuously resulting in the collisionCnt becoming equals to 4 for a single collision event. I need at least 4 objects of rainGroup group to touch the ground before it is game over. All help is welcome and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve this would be to give your rain drops a property that would denote whether they had collided or touched the ground. Then in your check see if that property was set and if it was not increment your counter and set the property.

I've [created a full JSFiddle as a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/m2otvx7r/4/) but the relevant code changes in your code might be something like this:

```
this.collisionChecker = this.physics.arcade.collide(this.ground, this.rainGroup, this.over);     //checks for collision between rain drops and ground

over: function(ground, rainDrop) {
    if (!rainDrop.hasTouchedGround) {
        collisionCnt++;
        rainDrop.hasTouchedGround = true;
        if (collisionCnt >= 4) {
            this.state.start('gameOver');
        }
    }
}
```

The second option is to kill rain drops when they touch the ground. That makes things much easier, but will remove the sprite from the display.

```
over: function(ground, rainDrop) {
    collisionCnt++;
    rainDrop.kill();
    if (collisionCnt >= 4) {
        this.state.start('gameOver');
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle example showing this option](https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/1cs8rjh8/1/).